# eclipse - Export android project for Android Studio - Dependencies error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I just downloaded Android Studio, and I want to import an existing android project from eclipse into android studio. However when importing, I encountered an error.

" Project ..\appcompat_v7_3 is missing. Needed by "project name". Make sure all dependencies are opened."

It seems like I need a support library, but I would prefer not to add it to my project.

Is there anyway I can import the android project into android studio without the need of a support library?
Also, how do I fix this error?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

well,I have encountered the same problem.
When I removed ' android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7 ' in the project.properties,the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Is your project running correctly in Eclipse?

Sorry I don't have the rep just to comment.

Try ensuring that your project is running without errors in Eclipse before attempting to export.